# WP Job Manager - Create Multi Select Field for Job type instead of multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, plugins

I would like to modify the default checkboxes for the job types to a multi select field as shown in the category field in the image:
[image]

This is the job_filters.php section for the category field: Could we "duplicate it" and change the key elements to "job type" elements or similiar?

```
<?php if ( $categories ) : ?>
    <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="search_categories[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $category ) ); ?>" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php elseif ( $show_categories && ! is_tax( \WP_Job_Manager_Post_Types::TAX_LISTING_CATEGORY ) && get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => \WP_Job_Manager_Post_Types::TAX_LISTING_CATEGORY ] ) ) : ?>
    <div class="search_categories">
        <label for="search_categories"><?php esc_html_e( 'Category', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
        <?php if ( $show_category_multiselect ) : ?>
            <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( [ 'taxonomy' => \WP_Job_Manager_Post_Types::TAX_LISTING_CATEGORY, 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'hide_empty' => true ] ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( [ 'taxonomy' => \WP_Job_Manager_Post_Types::TAX_LISTING_CATEGORY, 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => __( 'Any category', 'wp-job-manager' ), 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'multiple' => false, 'hide_empty' => true ] ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```